# LINQ Performance Optimization using Group By

Tags: c#, performance, linq, optimization, group-by

I've a group by clause in C# LINQ, it's taking more than 5 minutes to execute. In production environment timing out because of large scale data. Is there any way to optimize this LINQ query ? Appreciate any help.

```
var qFilingReview = (from x in FilingReviewsList
                    group x by new { x.filingAnswer.Grouping, x.filingAnswer.Instructions, x.filingReview.Name, x.filingQuestion.Number } into grp
                    select new { result = grp.FirstOrDefault() })
                         .ToList()
                         .OrderBy(k => k.result.filingQuestion.Id)
                         .ThenByDescending(k => k.result.filingAnswer.Id);
```

Comment: do you really need that `ToList` call ?

Comment: What is it? Linq to SQL? Entity Framework? usual linq to objects? If it maps to SQL query, then you need to use SQL Profiler to get Execution plan for executed SQL and find bottlenecks. Maybe there are some indexes missed

Comment: Thanks! Yes EF. I did it and I need to check if I can add some indexes to make it better. But removing unnecessary ToList() helps to optimize the performance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At first I think you must remove unnecessary ToList() calling.